# Create a master-detail table using Datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I was looking the official manual of Datatables and I found that: [manual Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/row_details.html)

I'm trying to make a master-detail table like this but I want to show the detail in other table, not in the master table.
I think that I can get the content of the row I click and send it using AJAX to do the query and show the content in the detail table.
I have the following code for load the datatables and can click in a row.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#PRESUP').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sRowSelect": "single"
        }
    } );
    $('#PRESUP_D').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
         "oTableTools": {
            "sRowSelect": "single"
         }
    } );
} );
```

PRESUP is the master table and PRESUP_D is the detail table.
I need to add to this function other function for get the value of the clicked row and for send it to an AJAX file.